# Returning JSON via Ajax with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to get a JSON from a PHP page, but always I receive 'undefined'.

My jQuery code is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#lista_partecipanti").click(function(){
            $.post( "application/third_party/php_files/lista_partecipanti.php",
            { 
                user_id:<? echo $user_id; ?> , jam_id:<? echo $id_jam; ?>
            }, 
            function(data)
            {
                if(data) {
                    $("#div_lista_partecipanti").html('test' + data[0].username);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error");                                     
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

$a_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$b_id = $_POST['jam_id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User a, Jam b WHERE a.id = b.owner AND a.id = $a_id AND b.id = $b_id");

if(mysql_num_rows() == 1) 
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $data = array(
            'username' =>$row['username'],
            'user_id' => $row['id']
    );
    $data = json_encode($data);
    echo $data;    
}
else
    return false;

mysql_close();
?>
```

---

#### Solved

I solved my problem, it was not a PHP problem but the error was in the jquery code.
I just added

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

before

```
$("#div_lista_partecipanti").html(data.username);
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Show us the returned response.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: The `while` loop is rather distracting - you've established there is only one row.

Comment: Ok thanks! I fixed it. By the way, the javascript code is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't specified otherwise, so PHP will claim that it is outputting an HTML document, and jQuery will treat the JSON as if it were HTML.

Add `header("Content-Type: application/json");` before you output anything from your PHP.

---

Secondly, your JSON text consists of a single object, not an array of objects.

`data[0].username` should be just `data.username`

Answer (score 0):

First you're very open to mysql injection, you should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements.

Second you shouldn't echo JSON inside the loop, it doesn't work like that, you need to add all your data to an array and then `json_encode` it and return it after the loop, although for your example it's only one item but still.

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$a_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$b_id = $_POST['jam_id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User a, Jam b WHERE a.id = b.owner AND a.id = $a_id AND b.id = $b_id");

if(mysql_num_rows() >= 1) {
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $data[] = array(
            'username' =>$row['username'],
            'user_id' => $row['id']
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo json_encode([]);
}
mysql_close();
```

Comment: The loop is a red herring. There is only one matching row … or there was in the original code. You changed the check condition.

Comment: yeah, made it make more sense.

Comment: I changed it, added the json header, but it still showing 'undefined'.

Comment: I changed the code to echo an empty array on error, does that help?

Comment: Check the console and see if anything is erroring, check [this](http://blog.bcdsoftware.com/2323/how-to-use-chrome-developer-tools-to-debug-ajax/).

Answer (score -1):

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "application/third_party/php_files/lista_partecipanti.php",
            data: "userid="+<?php echo $user_id; ?>+"&jam_id="<?php echo $id_jam; ?>,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                    ... 
                }
            }
        );
```